# Vector space property: distributivity

Tags: vector-spaces

I want to proof, using the axioms of a vector space, that:

$$(\alpha - \beta)\overrightarrow a = \alpha \overrightarrow a - \beta \overrightarrow a$$

My attempt:

$$(\alpha - \beta)\overrightarrow a = (\alpha + (-\beta))\overrightarrow a = \alpha \overrightarrow a + (-\beta) \overrightarrow a$$

I'm stuck here, I want to show that:

$$(-\beta) \overrightarrow a = -(\beta \overrightarrow a)$$

then use the definition of vector substraction. I tried this by showing that they both have $$\beta \overrightarrow a$$ as symmetric element but I would need to show uniqueness of symmetric elements then, wouldn't I?

EDIT: I cannot use $$(-1)\overrightarrow a = - \overrightarrow a$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\beta \vec{a}+(-\beta)\vec{a}=(\beta+(-\beta))\vec{a}=0\vec{a}=0$